# iOS, KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS [UITextField keyboardInputChangedSelection:]

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm getting the following error.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS  
KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 
[UITextField keyboardInputChangedSelection:]
```

Up till this latest crash report I've been unable t reproduce this crash.

I call this view controller from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` depending on whether a **passcode** / **pin** has been set in my app.

Now here's the strange thing.

The crash occurs in the following scenario.

1. I run my app without a pin set, I set the pin.
2. Then press the home button.
3. This view controller pops up and I enter the pin and the view is dismissed.
4. I then press the home button.
5. I enter the app, pin screen appears.
6. I press home.
7. Then enter the app and I get a crash.

I'm using arc and I reproduced the crash on iOS6.

Here's my code below, I just can't see the problem ?

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define PVSectionFooterDefault @"Enter your PIN"
#define PVSectionFooterInvalid @"Invalid!"
#define PVSectionFooterCorrect @"Correct!"

@interface PasscodeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, 
       UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UITableView *passcodeTable;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *passcodeTable;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField   *txtPassword;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *lblMessage;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "PasscodeViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation PasscodeViewController
@synthesize passcodeTable;
@synthesize txtPassword;
@synthesize lblMessage;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //[passcodeTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //[passcodeTable setBackgroundView:nil];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

    lblMessage.shadowColor       = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblMessage.shadowOffset      = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    lblMessage.font              = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    lblMessage.textColor         = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    lblMessage.text = PVSectionFooterDefault;

    txtPassword.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    txtPassword.accessibilityLabel = @"Enter PIN";
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(willShowKeyboard:) 
             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(didShowKeyboard:) 
             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)willShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)didShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Table view methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
              numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+205, 
                    cell.frame.origin.y+7, 90, 31);

        txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        txtPassword.delegate = self;
        txtPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        txtPassword.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        txtPassword.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        txtPassword.contentVerticalAlignment = 
                     UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        txtPassword.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        txtPassword.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;    
        txtPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;
        txtPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;    

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Enter PIN";

        [cell addSubview:txtPassword];

        [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];     
    }
    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    lblMessage.text = PVSectionFooterDefault;   
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
           shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
                       replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    BOOL res = TRUE;
    NSString *newString = [textField.text 
             stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range 
                                     withString:string];

    if ([newString length] == 4) {
        NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *strPassword = [myDefaults stringForKey:@"pass"];

        if (strPassword == nil) {
            strPassword = @"";
        }

        if (![newString isEqualToString:strPassword]) {
            lblMessage.text = PVSectionFooterInvalid;
        } else {
            lblMessage.text = PVSectionFooterCorrect;

            AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate*) 
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appDel.gbooShowingGetStartedPasswordAsk = FALSE;
            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    } else if ([newString length] < 4) {
        lblMessage.text = PVSectionFooterDefault;
    }

    res = !([newString length] > 4);

    return res;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

app delegate did launch

```
if (![strPassword isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.gbooShowingGetStartedPasswordAsk = TRUE;

        lvc = [[PasscodeViewController alloc] 
               initWithNibName:@"PasscodeView" bundle:nil];

        lvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460); 

        [window addSubview:lvc.view];
    }
```

and....

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (self.gbooShowingGetStartedPasswordAsk == FALSE) {

        NSString *strPassword = [myDefaults stringForKey:@"pass"];
        if (strPassword == nil) {
            strPassword = @"";
        }

        if (![strPassword isEqualToString:@""]) {
            lvc = [[PasscodeViewController alloc] 
                   initWithNibName:@"PasscodeView" bundle:nil];
            int th = self.window.frame.size.height;
            lvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, th); 

            lvc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

            [window addSubview:lvc.view];
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have to tried enabling zombies?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, that didn't help

Comment: It might not be the best idea to store the passcode as plain text in the user defaults. Use some kind of hashing instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider when `lvc` is not `nil`, and has a superview, and `applicationWillEnterForeground:` is called, and takes the branch into the main block of code there. You assign `lvc` to a new instance of a `PasscodeViewController`, which likely causes the old value of `lvc` to be deallocated. However, its `view` property has a superview, so is not deallocated along with it. These living objects may yet produce notifications or actions that the deallocated view controller is still listening to. I also notice that you're not always unsubscribing from notifications in dealloc or `nil`ing the text field's delegate.

My suggestions, then, are 1) make sure you remove `lvc`'s view before instantiating another instance and 2) make sure your `PasscodeViewController`'s `dealloc` method cleans up possibly dangling references that `NSNotificationCenter` has.

Your `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method becomes:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (self.gbooShowingGetStartedPasswordAsk == FALSE) {

        NSString *strPassword = [myDefaults stringForKey:@"pass"];
        if (strPassword == nil) {
            strPassword = @"";
        }

        if (![strPassword isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [lvc.view removeFromSuperview]; // This line prevents the view from persisting
            lvc = [[PasscodeViewController alloc] 
                   initWithNibName:@"PasscodeView" bundle:nil];
            int th = self.window.frame.size.height;
            lvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, th); 

            lvc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

            [window addSubview:lvc.view];
        }
    }
}
```

Your `PasscodeViewController`'s `dealloc` should look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    if (txtPassword.delegate == self) {
        txtPassword.delegate = nil; //docs indicate this is still an `assign` property so is not auto-zeroing in ARC and iOS 5+
    }
}
```

With these changes, there should be no more dangling references to a deallocated view controller, and no orphaned views in your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

And

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

look suspicious for me. I'm not an ARC fan, but it seems your are plausibly deallocating a UITextField when you are removing your view from its parent. It can appears in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

call.

So you should init and alloc your txtPassword on viewDidLoad instead into the cell(s) initialization.

Like you said you are leaving and restarting your app from background. If your cell has been freed, you may reassign new txtPassword, and still leaving the older into  the last cell. So you possibly can have multiple txtPassword with the same delegate assignement. If your view is undisplaying, the reference of the txtPassword will no longer be valid before you can return the UITextfield method.

So like i said, be sure to assign your txtPassword only one time. So put alloc it in viewDidLoad, and free it in viewDidUnLoad.

Remember i'm only guessing. Hope it will help you.

Comment: that does improve things, but in the simulator, using the lock screen feature, this causes similar errors. Hmmmm

Comment: You should isolate part of your code, where it seems suspicious and check if it is still working. Replace UITextfield delegate method with blank  statement, and check if it's still crash. If that doesn't help, use a nil txtPassword and check again. If that's not help, uncomment your NSNotification and try again. That's caveman debugging, but you will spend 15 min to check it. Because sophisticated debugging won't help you. Your code is small, so you'll see soon what's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Removing a view from its superview in a textfield callback for a textfield on the same view probably is not a good idea in any case. When the password is entered correctly, try resigning the first responder from the textfield, then either hide your passcode view, or remove the view, but keep a reference to the passcode controller somewhere (e.g. in the app delegate) so the view is not released by ARC (and with it its passcode textfield).

Comment: Thats' what was it was suggested to Jules. ARC is good, but make code harder to debug.

Comment: Always, always, always set the delegate to nil before there's a chance the recipient of the delegate call is deallocated. In this case, before self is deallocated, you have to set the delegate of the text field to nil.

Comment: Furthermore, what's the point of creating dynamic cells in a tableview if you're only creating one cell? It's much more reliable to create a static cell in self's viewDidLoad for example, and have it as a property of self. This way you can clear the delegate easily and/or reassign first responder.